# How to build an ADT for sets of numbers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

How to build an ADT for sets of numbers in C# with the following properties:
Set Union, Intersection, difference, size, add an element to a set, delete an element from a set.

Could anyone please show me a simple program that uses one of above operations?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has built the set class for you: [`System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Comment: Or, generally, any class which implements `ISet<T>` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx). The operations you describe define the interface.